# req.body returns undefined when I use express router, even though I used express.urlencoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, express-router

Here is my server.js code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const articleRouter = require("./routes/articles");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use("/articles", articleRouter);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const articles = [
    {
      title: "Test Article 1",
      createdAt: new Date(),
      description: "Test description 1",
    },
    {
      title: "Test Article 2",
      createdAt: new Date(),
      description: "Test description 2",
    },
  ];
  res.render("articles/index", { articles: articles });
});

// app.post("/articles", (req, res) => {
//   console.log(req.body);
// });

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000...");
});
```

This code (which I commented) works fine

```js
app.post("/articles", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

But when I try to do the same thing with router, it returns undefined. Here is my articles.js code from routes folder:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
  res.render("articles/new");
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here id new.ejs code, where the from is:

```js
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mb-4">New Article</h1>
    <form action="/articles" method="post">
      <%- include('_form_fields') %>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem occurs only when I try to do this in router file. I would be very thankful if anyone can tell me what exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use any router after using middlewares.
I think using `express.json()` is required for parsing json from body of http request

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// ... any middleware
app.use("/articles", articleRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the app to the router file and then use it regularly like this:

```
 const articleRouter = require("./routes/articles");

 articleRouter(app);
```

in the `articleRouter` file:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.post("/", (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
}
```